# Correctly output dictionary to a file (fimi format) python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file containing string values separated by space "  ". I need to set each of those string values to be equal to a some number. 
So far I have done a reading from the file to a dictionary where each unique key corresponds to a value number.

```
import collections 

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
     c = collections.Counter(f.read().split())

newvalue = 0
for key, value in c.iteritems():
    newvalue +=1
        c[key] =  newvalue
    print key, newvalue
```

My problem is now that I don't know how to write the output in another file, keeping this structure:

my text file:

- computer phone library desk book
- book yard spring phone
- book spring

desired output file:

- 1 2 3 4 5
- 5 6 7 2
- 5 7

Can someone please help me?

Comment: how does your text file looks like?

Comment: provide a sample of test.txt.

Comment: Do you have the output you want on the console - is the `print` statement producing the correct results?

Comment: replace `print` for a `write` on a file object?

Comment: The file contains different number of words in each row. But some of those words are repeating. I would like to keep the same number for the repeating word and keep the rows the same (only now, the words replaced by corresponding number)

Comment: The print statement is printing out each key with the corresponding number, but not as my desired output file (please see example above)

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

1. `Counter` objects do not have an `iteritems` method.
2. Indentation.
3. Splitting the whole file at once produces a single list, destroying the desired layout.

Here is a working sample that does what you want. The biggest change is to preserve the layout of the input file by using nested lists.

```
import collections 

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f: # open the file
    lines = [] # initialize a list
    for line in f: # for each line in the file,
        # add a list of that line's words to the initialized list
        lines.append(line.split())
    # save a Counter out of the concatenation of those nested lists
    c = collections.Counter(sum(lines, []))

with open('testout.txt', 'w') as output: # start a file
    for line in lines: # for each list in the list we made,
        result = [] # initialize a list
        for word in line: # for each word in the nested list,
            # add that word's count to the initialized list
            result.append(str(c[word]))
        # write a string representation of the list to the file
        output.write(' '.join(result) + '\n')
```

Comment: Actually I get back the dictionary: (from the example above) {'yard' : 1,'spring': 2,'library' :3,'phone' :4,'computer' :5, 'book' : 6} key and value printed on one line.

Comment: I would like to have those words to be replaced by the numeric values, but each one to stay on the same row.

Comment: I tried to create a list of list from the rows in the  file, but I am stuck on how to replace a list value to a value from the dictionary. Is it possible?